# How to sum each row and append the sum into the same list?

Tags: python, list

```
def row_sums(square):
    """takes such a (possibly magic) square as a parameter and returns a list of the row sums"""
    total_each_row = 0
    combine_each_total = []    
    for row in square: #row is an entire row
        for cell in row: #cell is an element of row
            total_each_row += cell  #possible error 


        combine_each_total.append(total_each_row) #possible error 
    return combine_each_total



magic_square = [
    [2, 7, 6],
    [9, 5, 1],
    [4, 3, 8]
]
print(row_sums(magic_square))
```

This program running out as [15, 30, 45] but what I want to get is [15, 15, 15] as the sum of each row and allocate the sums in the same list.

After the first row finished its sum calculation, how to make a new total for the second and the following rows for each one and append each sum into the same list?

The square would be containing all the integers from 1 up to n**2 inclusive.

In the end, returns a list of the row sums

Are there any other ways to achieve the result without using the built-in sum function in this case?
(Sorry I should emphasize this point)

Comment: So in the end you'll have an array of 4 rows/arrays each with 3 numbers, or 3 rows each with 4 numbers, or 4 rows each with 4 numbers?

Comment: returns a list of the row sums. thanks

Comment: Okay, you don't need a function for this. Added a one liner as an answer

Comment: @GrandPhuba Are there any other ways to achieve the result without using the built-in sum function in this case? (Sorry I should emphasize this point)

Comment: Yes, it's the last example in my answer

Comment: What should the value of `total_each_row` be when you begin adding up the values in a certain row? Is there anything in your code that causes this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
magic_square = [
    [2, 7, 6],
    [9, 5, 1],
    [4, 3, 8]
]

# functional/pythonic way
sums = [sum(row) for row in magic_square]  # [15, 15, 15]


# if you want to make it longer
def row_sums(square):
   return [sum(row) for row in square]
row_sums(magic_square)  # [15, 15, 15]


#if you want to make it even longer
def row_sums(square):
   sums = []
   for row in square:
      row_total = 0
      for number in row:
          row_total += number
      sums.append(row_total)    
   return sums
row_sums(magic_square)  # [15, 15, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use pythons sum function for each row.

```
Arr=[]
for row in square:
    Arr.append(sum(row))
return Arr
```

If you want to use your code the problem with it is that you dont make sure that your sum row var equals to 0 so its keeping the count from last row.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to reinitialize `combine_each_total` to `0` before summing again for new row.

```py
def row_sums(square):
    """takes such a (possibly magic) square as a parameter and returns a list of the row sums"""

    combine_each_total = []    
    for row in square: #row is an entire row
        total_each_row = 0
        for cell in row: #cell is an element of row
            total_each_row += cell  #possible error 


        combine_each_total.append(total_each_row) #possible error 
    return combine_each_total



magic_square = [
    [2, 7, 6],
    [9, 5, 1],
    [4, 3, 8]
]
print(row_sums(magic_square))
```

output:

```
[15,15,15]
```